# Informatica data value

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have birthdate column and I need to find out the below way and update

IF birthdate greater than 25 years then add date 10 years to target column value

IF birthdate lessthan 25 years then  make null

How can we achieve this using Expression transformation in Informatica

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: How can a birthdate be more than 25 years? Or do you mean the current *age*?

Comment: Hi Marc, I mean current age

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two ports for TargetColumn: in_TargetColumn as input port and out_TargetColumn as output port, try the below function as an expresion for out_TargetColumn:

`IIF( DATE_DIFF (SYSDATE, BIRTHDATE, 'Y') > 25, in_TargetColumn + 10, NULL)`